# Query rule, my documents with space

Tags: 2013, search

I have a query rule like this:
http://screencast.com/t/ecFYmwDyhk3

More link goes to the following url

```
 https://be-prpsp029.com/search/Pages/My-Search-Results.aspx?k={subjectTerms}
```

This works perfectly fine for keywords with one workd

However, when the  keyword is two words, the subject terms goes with `%20` between the words, and therefore nothing is found:

http://screencast.com/t/tySgbryT

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, the %20 is the way HTML encodes spaces.  So while the URL will have "?k=John%20Doe", it should still be "John Doe" outside of an HTML encoding (I mean, go on google and search somthing with spaces, it'll have the %20" or something similar).

Comment: I know that, but check the 2nd screenshot, sharepoint puts the %20 on the textbox, and then search wont return any results.

Comment: Quick question before I provide my answer, just to make sure I give a correct one.  How are you writing your query?  Are you creating it through code by yourself, or just through the application?

Comment: I do it through site settings, search query rules, launch query builder.  query is  {subjectTerms} Author:{User.Name}  Path:https://be-prpsp029.com/, see screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/zdcdED9vZIdJ

Comment: is My-search-results.aspx a page you made by yourself, filtering after querystring?

Comment: no custom code, its a page, just like the search results page, but using a different result source that filters on 2 people fields, Contacts and Author, I didnt do any custom code, http://screencast.com/t/DkeVKIaFhI0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the answer here:

(explanation  its too long to be posted as an answer here)
http://www.luisevalencia.com/2014/08/18/fix-double-encoding-bug-aka-sharepoint-display-templates-promoted-results/

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the problem is the way you construct the 'More' Link? You are using {subjectTerms} in the more link, which is the search terms without the original Action term which fired the special Result Block. So the first page is firing the Query Rule, but the More page isn't.

Perhaps using {searchboxquery} in the more link would cause the rule to fire on the second page.

Answer (score 1):

The Query Conditions part of the Add Query Rule controls how the {searchboxquery} (the original thing the user typed) gets transformed into {subjectTerms} and {actionTerms}.

Are you using Advanced Query Text Match? And which of the options do you have selected to:

- Assign the entire query to {subjectTerms}
- Assign match to {subjectTerms], unmatched terms to {actionTerms}
- Assign match to {actionTerms}, unmatched terms to {subjectTerms}

In any event I don't think the problem is with the query for your result block, but rather for your query conditions and how "and the" is getting assigned to {subjectTerms}.

PS: Not sure if this counts as an answer, but I would have commented on Fletchonides post, only I don't have enough points to comment. Kinda a catch 22 isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `decodeURI()` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp)

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var url = window.location.href,
    vars = {};
    url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        key = decodeURIComponent(key);
        value = decodeURIComponent(value);
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: how can I use it inside a sharepoint content search webpart?  or in the query role?